# How to delete a installed application using AppId in inno setup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

Currently i have used the following code to delete the old version directory of my application, below code works fine by finding the application with the app name. I want to find the application using it UNIQUE APPID, Can someone please help me out regarding this issue.

```
procedure DeleteExistingVersion(); begin   
MsgBox('Deletion Starts',mbInformation, MB_OK);

if (DirExists (ExpandConstant('{pf}\APPLICATION NAME'))) then  
begin

DelTree(ExpandConstant('{pf}\APPLICATION NAME'), True, True, True);
MsgBox('Deletion Ends', mbInformation, MB_OK);   
end; 
end;
```

Comment: You could call `{uninstallexe}` of previous version - example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000296/innosetup-how-to-automatically-uninstall-previous-installed-version) and even better one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739317/how-to-detect-old-installation-and-offer-removal)

Comment: You should uninstall it. Not just delete the folder tree.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments @RobeN,TLama  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000296/innosetup-how-to-automatically-uninstall-previous-installed-version) helps me to solve this issue. Now my apllication uninstalls existing version completely before installing new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to uninstall previous version of your app instead of just deleting the tree by calling `{uninstallexe}`. You can check two solutions that were posted earlier:

[InnoSetup: How to automatically uninstall previous installed version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000296/innosetup-how-to-automatically-uninstall-previous-installed-version)

[How to detect old installation and offer removal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739317/how-to-detect-old-installation-and-offer-removal)

Comment: Note that unless there is some special reason there is no need to uninstall your application before upgrading it with a later build of the installer.