# How to overwrite on install but not on change in Inno Setup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I know how to overwrite the files using this method

```
[Files]
Source: "Project\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs onlyifdoesntexist; Permissions: everyone-full
```

But when I change the program using the *Change* option in *'Install Or Change Program'* section I want to not overwrite the files.

I create the change option for my installer like this:

```
[setup]
AppModifyPath="{srcexe}" /modify=1
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

First, your code seems wrong. With the [`onlyifdoesntexist` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=onlyifdoesntexist), the files are never overwritten, contrary to what you claim. So for most purposes, simply using this flag will do.

---

Anyway, a solution is to create two `[Files]` entries, one that overwrites and one that does not. And use the Pascal scripting to pick the entry for a respective installation mode.

```
[Files]
Source: "Project\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ... onlyifdoesntexist; Check: IsUpgrade
Source: "Project\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ...; Check: not IsUpgrade
```

Example of `IsUpgrade` implementation:

```pascal
[Code]

function IsUpgrade: Boolean;
var
  S: string;
  InnoSetupReg: string;
  AppPathName: string;
begin  
  InnoSetupReg :=
    'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#SetupSetting("AppId")}_is1';
  { The ExpandConstant is here for Inno Script Studio, }
  { which generated AppId in a form of GUID. }
  { The leading { of the GUID has to be doubled in Inno Setup, }
  { and the ExpandConstant collapses that back to single {. }
  InnoSetupReg := ExpandConstant(InnoSetupReg);

  AppPathName := 'Inno Setup: App Path';
  Result :=
    RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, InnoSetupReg, AppPathName, S) or
    RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, InnoSetupReg, AppPathName, S);
end;
```

See also [Pascal scripting: Check parameters](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck).