# Duplicate entry in installed program when Inno Setup installation is upgraded with MSI/WiX installation

Tags: windows, wix, inno-setup

I have some DLLs and want them to be installed on Windows. I packaged them to both .msi (using WiX) and .exe (using Inno Setup). However, when installed both .msi and .exe on one machine, they looks like two program. Since I check the uninstall, and there are two programs there (one is installed with .exe and other is .msi)

My goal is to make they looks like same program, i.e. when .exe is installed and then .msi is also installed, the program should overwrite .exe, i.e. there should only be one program in the uninstall tab.

How can I achieve this? Should I use same upgradeCode or productCode?

Comment: Can you explain us, why do you have two installers, in the first place?

Comment: I first ship the exe and then I want to change to msi. So for existing customers I want to make it convenient to overwrite the previous program installed by exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your MSI installer uninstall the existing Inno Setup installation, before installing itself.

You can lookup a path to Inno Setup uninstaller in registry.

See also:

- [How to detect old installation and offer removal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11739317/850848)
- [InnoSetup: How to automatically uninstall previous installed version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2000296/850848)

Comment: I have the same problem.  Innosetup uses english words for the AppId whereas Wix uses Guids.  The Wix upgrade-related tags seem to insist on Guids.

Comment: You can use GUID in Inno Setup too. But the problem is not in AppID. You just cannot make these systems compatible.