# Inno setup- How to 'remove' SQL native client unattended

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to check for previous installation of SQL native Client 11, before installation and if found, it needs to be uninstalled. [Executing UninstallString in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222356/executing-uninstallstring-in-inno-setup)

Things work fine, but I want the Uninstall to be performed unattended. I am getting options `Modify,Repair,Remove` in the wizard. How can I select `Remove` by default and proceed with uninstall silently?

Note: It uses `MsiExec` and  `/U /SILENT` parameters in the `Exec` function seems to just exit without any errors.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
MsiExec.exe /x{FA5C8C7E-3939-4219-A18E-0519832FE06A} /qn
```

(I found the options on http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/msiexec.html)

Comment: The official documentation would be more appropriate: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988.aspx