# inno issue: Unable to execute file retrieved from RegQueryStringValue

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

Execute/Run the following Inno code and I got error message. The file "c:\xxxx-runtime\unins000.exe" does exist.

Error message:

```
Unable to execute file:
"c:\xxxx-runtime\unins000.exe"
CreateProcess failed; code 267.
The directory name is invalid.
```

Inno code shown below:

```
[UninstallRun]
Filename: "{code:ARGetUninstallString}";
;Filename: {code:ARGetUninstallString};   -- same result

[Code]
function ARGetUninstallString(p: String): String;
var
  sUnInstPath: String;
  sUnInstallString: String;
begin
  sUnInstPath := ExpandConstant('Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\xxxx_is1');
  sUnInstallString := '';
  if not RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString) then
    RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString);
  Result := sUnInstallString;
end;
```

However, It works fine IF I replace

```
[UninstallRun]
Filename: "{code:ARGetUninstallString}";
```

With

```
[UninstallRun]
Filename: "c:\xxxx-runtime\unins000.exe";
```

Would any Inno expert knows what the issue is?

Comment: Note how in all existing questions about this topic, the `UninstallString` is split to program path and arguments. With program path being wrapped in double quotes, that need to be removed.

Comment: Thanks for comment, Martin. I found the problem - In my script [Run] section, I install an application which will write to Registry. The [UninstallRun] actually executes during setup, at this time the application in [Run] section has not been executed and so the reg is not being updated. The sUnInstallString (or Result) contains the empty string. I am still trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is my solution, basically execute the xxxxx-runtime.exe in the [code] section before getting the path from the reg. Following is source code:

```
[Files]              
Source: ".\xxxxx-runtime.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall

[UninstallRun]
Filename: {code:GetUninstallString}; BeforeInstall: SetUninstallString; RunOnceId: {code:GetUninstallString}

[Code]
var
uninstallString: String;

function getUninstallString(p: String): String;
begin
  Result := uninstallString;
end;

// execute xxxxx-runtime.exe
procedure exe();
var
  iResultCode: Integer;
begin
  Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\xxxxx-runtime.exe'), '/SILENT /NORESTART /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES','', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, iResultCode);
end;

procedure SetUninstallString();
var
  sUnInstPath: String;
  sUnInstallString: String;
begin
  exe();
  sUnInstPath := ExpandConstant('Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\xxxxx_is1');
  sUnInstallString := '';
  if not RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString) then
    RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString);
  uninstallString := RemoveQuotes(sUnInstallString);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have found yourself, `{code:}` constant is evaluated on install time.

So instead, implement your code completely in `[Code]` section, not using `[UninstallRun]` section.

```pascal
[Code]

procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usPostUninstall { or usUninstall } then
  begin
    { Use RegQueryStringValue and Exec here }
  end;
end;
```

---

Though you need to fix your code that resolves command-line for uninstaller. Note how in all existing questions about this topic, the `UninstallString` is split to program path and arguments. With program path being wrapped in double quotes, that need to be removed.

See [Executing UninstallString in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42222356/850848).