# How to uninstall a program mistakenly installed in the "Program Files(x86)" folder and install it anew in the 64-bit "Program Files" folder

Tags: inno-setup

I am using innoSetup to create a software installer.
However, by default, innoSetup installs to "Program Files(x86)", which I have mistakenly distributed to my users.

And many users install the software in the x86 directory using a 64-bit Windows environment.

I created an installer for the new version of the software with innoSetup and designed it to install correctly in "Program Files" for 64-bit.

However, the programs already installed in "Program Files(x86)" are not uninstalled and remain.
How can I uninstall them?

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45006468/uninstall-32-bit-application-and-install-64-bit-application/45009456?noredirect=1#comment132623943_45009456) exists in the past on stack overflow, but it did not solve my problem.

I had initially written the following code.
This was installed in the "Program Files(x86)" folder, even when used in a Windows 64-bit environment

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "testApp"
#define MyAppVersion "1.00"
#define MyAppPublisher "taichi"
#define MyAppURL "https://testApp.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "testApp.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{xxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxx}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={autopf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
; Uncomment the following line to run in non administrative install mode (install for current user only.)
;PrivilegesRequired=lowest
OutputDir=C:\Users\taichi\Desktop
OutputBaseFilename=testAppSetup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern

[Code]

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function GetUninstallString(): String;
var
  sUnInstPath: String;
  sUnInstallString: String;
begin
  sUnInstPath := ExpandConstant('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#emit SetupSetting("AppId")}_is1');
  sUnInstallString := '';
  if not RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString) then
    RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString);
  Result := sUnInstallString;
end;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function IsUpgrade(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (GetUninstallString() <> '');
end;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function UnInstallOldVersion(): Integer;
var
  sUnInstallString: String;
  iResultCode: Integer;
begin
// Return Values:
// 1 - uninstall string is empty
// 2 - error executing the UnInstallString
// 3 - successfully executed the UnInstallString

  // default return value
  Result := 0;

  // get the uninstall string of the old app
  sUnInstallString := GetUninstallString();
  if sUnInstallString <> '' then begin
    sUnInstallString := RemoveQuotes(sUnInstallString);
    if Exec(sUnInstallString, '/SILENT /NORESTART /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES','', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, iResultCode) then
      Result := 3
    else
      Result := 2;
  end else
    Result := 1;
end;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if (CurStep=ssInstall) then
  begin
    if (IsUpgrade()) then
    begin
      UnInstallOldVersion();
    end;
  end;
end;

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\taichi\Documents\hold\testAppDevelop\dist\testApp\testApp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
                                                           

[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: runasoriginaluser nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

After modifying the code as follows, the software was installed in Program Files. However, the files in Program Files(x86) were not uninstalled.

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "testApp"
#define MyAppVersion "1.00"
#define MyAppPublisher "taichi"
#define MyAppURL "https://testApp.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "testApp.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{xxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxx}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={autopf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
; Uncomment the following line to run in non administrative install mode (install for current user only.)
;PrivilegesRequired=lowest
OutputDir=C:\Users\taichi\Desktop
OutputBaseFilename=testAppSetup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
ArchitecturesAllowed=x64

[Code]

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function GetUninstallString(): String;
var
  sUnInstPath: String;
  sUnInstallString: String;
begin
  sUnInstPath := ExpandConstant('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#emit SetupSetting("AppId")}_is1');
  sUnInstallString := '';
  if not RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString) then
    RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString);
  Result := sUnInstallString;
end;

function GetUninstallString32: string;
var
  sUnInstPath: string;
  sUnInstallString: String;
begin
  Result := '';
  sUnInstPath := ExpandConstant('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{{A227028A-40D7-4695-8BA9-41DF6A3895C7}_is1'); { Your App GUID/ID }
  sUnInstallString := '';
  if not RegQueryStringValue(HKLM32, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString) then
    RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString);
  Result := sUnInstallString;
end;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function IsUpgrade(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (GetUninstallString() <> '');
end;

function IsUpgrade32(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (GetUninstallString32() <> '');
end;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function UnInstallOldVersion(): Integer;
var
  sUnInstallString: String;
  iResultCode: Integer;
begin
// Return Values:
// 1 - uninstall string is empty
// 2 - error executing the UnInstallString
// 3 - successfully executed the UnInstallString

  // default return value
  Result := 0;

  // get the uninstall string of the old app
  sUnInstallString := GetUninstallString();
  if sUnInstallString <> '' then begin
    sUnInstallString := RemoveQuotes(sUnInstallString);
    if Exec(sUnInstallString, '/SILENT /NORESTART /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES','', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, iResultCode) then
      Result := 3
    else
      Result := 2;
  end else
    Result := 1;
end;

function UnInstallOldVersion32(): Integer;
var
  sUnInstallString: String;
  iResultCode: Integer;
begin
// Return Values:
// 1 - uninstall string is empty
// 2 - error executing the UnInstallString
// 3 - successfully executed the UnInstallString

  // default return value
  Result := 0;

  sUnInstallString := GetUninstallString32();
  if sUnInstallString <> '' then begin
    sUnInstallString := RemoveQuotes(sUnInstallString);
    if Exec(sUnInstallString, '/SILENT /NORESTART /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES','', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, iResultCode) then
      Result := 3
    else
      Result := 2;
  end else
    Result := 1;
end;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if (CurStep=ssInstall) then
  begin
    if (IsUpgrade()) then
    begin
      UnInstallOldVersion();
    end;
  end;
  begin
    UnInstallOldVersion32();
  end;
end;

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\taichi\Documents\hold\testAppDevelop\dist\testApp\testApp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
                                                           

[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: runasoriginaluser nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: The *"are not uninstalled"* is not very useful problem description. What does happen exactly? What did you do to debug the problem? I do not see any logging in your code. That's what you should start with.

Comment: i would argue it is not a critical issue. My installer puts both the 32 bit and 64 bit builds in the same folder (x86). As for your issue, why not keep things simple? Correct the installer and ask your users to uninstall the current version and re-install the correct one.