# How to avoid InnoSetup from creating multiple versions in control panels?

Tags: version, inno-setup, uninstallation

I'm using InnoSetup to install my applications, but the problem is, whenever I change application version, it creates another item in control panel, despite these basically overwrite each other. So all I need is to let InnoSetup always use the same registry entry for the uninstallation in the control panels. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14015627/62576

Comment: That's not standard Inno Setup behavior. You must have something wrong in your script (something about `AppId`). We need [mcve]. - @KenWhite There's no need to uninstall the previous version, Inno Setup should "overwrite" the previous version.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: The part I was referring to was the posted answer to the linked question about consistency in the AppID, which would result in only one entry in the Control Panel.

Comment: @KenWhite OK, I see now!