# Inno Setup: How to uninstall app when I click installer after same version app been installed?

Tags: inno-setup

I already read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14446755/910074), but it doesn't fit my need. I have a installer built by Inno Setup. When the app been installed, the user wants to "**Right Click**" on the installer and choose "Uninstall" to uninstall the app. Is that possible?

Comment: I think a Windows Explorer shell extension is needed to insert this Uninstall menu item to the context menu showed after right clicking.

Comment: It's too complicated to try to add a context menu item for only a specific file (especially one whose name may change later).
You can add in the `InitializeSetup` event a check if the application is already installed, and create a custom form or dialog box that will be displayed to the user and ask whether to uninstall. If he chooses to uninstall, the uninstallation file in the installation folder will be run.

Comment: What if they just run the installer again - you could have an option to uninstall?

Comment: @StayOnTarget Run the installer again, then trigger the uninstaller. I'm ok with that.