# Command Line Parms: Function Return Type As Array?

Tags: arrays, function, types, inno-setup

Here's the [current problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633180/update-installed-recent-inno-version-but-remove-older-non-inno-versions-before-r):
Executing an uninstall string with *command line parameters* following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2099805/850848):
Here's what we have in the form of non-functioning code:

```
const MAX_PATH = 260;
function GetUninstallString(): TArrayOfString;
var
  sUnInstPath: String;
  sUnInstallString: String;
  sUnInstallStringPrm: String;

begin
sUnInstPath := ExpandConstant('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#MyAppName}');
sUnInstallString := '';
if not RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString) then
RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString);

if sUnInstallString = '' Then
Begin
sUnInstPath := ExpandConstant('Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#MyAppName}');
RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString);
End;
if sUnInstallString <> '' Then
Begin
sUnInstallStringPrm:= copy(sUnInstallString, pos(' ', sUnInstallString) + 1, MAX_PATH);
MsgBox(sUnInstallStringPrm, mbInformation, MB_OK);
Delete(sUnInstallString, pos(' ', sUnInstallString), MAX_PATH);
End;
Result := [sUnInstallString, UnInstallStringPrm];
end;


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function IsUpgrade(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (GetUninstallString() <> '');
end;


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function UnInstallOldVersion(): Integer;
var
  sUnInstallString: String;
  iResultCode: Integer;
begin
// Return Values:
// 1 - uninstall string is empty
// 2 - error executing the UnInstallString
// 3 - successfully executed the UnInstallString

  // default return value
  Result := 0;

  // get the uninstall string of the old app
  sUnInstallString := GetUninstallString();
  if sUnInstallString <> '' then begin
    sUnInstallString := RemoveQuotes(sUnInstallString);
    if ShellExec('open', sUnInstallString, '','', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, iResultCode) then
    Result := 3
    else
    Result := 2;
  end else
  Result := 1;
end;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if (CurStep=ssInstall) then
  begin
    if (IsUpgrade()) then
    begin
      UnInstallOldVersion();
    end;
  end;
end;
```

There is very little info on how to use **GetUninstallString** in this context. Possible at all?
Not sure if, as an alternative, the string array containing *sUnInstallString...* can be passed as a parameter within the above fixture, albeit the return type as array appears to fit a little better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetUninstallString` is used twice in [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2000296/850848#2099805).

1. In `IsUpgrade`
2. and in `UnInstallOldVersion`.

In `IsUpgrade` it's only tested for non-empty value.

In `UnInstallOldVersion` it is executed.

So make the function return whole `UninstallString` as a simple string.

For `IsUpgrade` it is enough.

And do the actual parsing to program path and its arguments in the `UnInstallOldVersion` only.

---

Also you should:

- Handle a situation where there's no space in the string (no parameters)
- The path to the uninstaller can contain spaces too (and it typically will as the uninstallers tend to be in `Program Files`).

Comment: Thanks very much for helping out. In this case Wise used 8.3 names so the space thing is easy- but yeah. :)